# Laravel - Getting empty dataset when retrieving from DB

Tags: php, database, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to populate a select dropdown but not seeing the values come through.

**Controller:**

```
public function create()
{
    $employees = Employee::get();

    $am = DB::table('employees')
        ->where('department', 'Account Manager')
        ->select('id', 'name')
        ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
        ->get();

    $pm = DB::table('employees')
        ->where('department', 'Project Manager')
        ->select('id', 'name')
        ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
        ->get();

    $employees->am = $am;
    $employees->pm = $pm;

    return view('projects/create', [
        'employees' => $employees
        ]);
}
```

**View:**

```
<div class="form-group">
                  <label>Account Manager</label>
                  <select class="form-control" name="am">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    @foreach ($employees as $employee)
                      <option value="{{ $employee->am['id'] }}">{{ $employee->am['name'] }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Project Manager</label>
                  <select class="form-control" name="pm">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    @foreach ($employees as $employee)
                      <option value="{{ $employee->pm['id'] }}">{{ $employee->pm['name'] }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                  </select>
                </div>
```

So, I know something is working because the dropdowns are showing there are 5 spaces which are the number of records in the DB but they are all blank. Doing a var_dump shows it to be NULL. Also, it is not taking into account the WHERE clause as both dropdowns show 5 spaces rather than 3 for Project Managers and 2 for Account Managers.

My Models do not have any relationship set up. Does it have to? Because I did a join for a different view and it works just fine.

My DB tables look like the following:

**Projects:**

```
id
name
am_id
pm_id
```

**Employees:**

```
id
name
department
```

Any ideas how to have the values populate in the dropdown?

Comment: Have you tried `@foreach ($employees->am as $employee)`?

Comment: That errors out and says "Undefined Property $am"

Comment: If you use the foreach modification I said above, you'd want to change your `<option>` code as well. Maybe to this: `<option value="{{ $employee->id }}">{{ $employee->name }}</option>` (I'm not sure if the `$employee` will be an array or an object.)

Comment: Thank you! That worked but I'm wondering why so I can understand it better. My other question located here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41203590/laravel-multiple-foreign-keys-and-getting-id was able to do it the original way I had it.

Comment: Use https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html , it's the easiest way to generate select elements on a form in laravel application

Comment: Thanks I have used that previously but found that all the added code to add in bootstrap classes made it just easier to use plain old HTML to create the forms.

Comment: I am just trying to figure out why in this case I have to do `($employees->am as $employee` in the foreach and `$employee->name` but in my previous questions (linked above), I did `$projects as $project` and `$project->am->name`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

```
$employeeAm = Employee::where('department', 'Account Manager')
        ->select('id', 'name')
        ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
        ->get();
$employeePm = Employee::where('department', 'Project Manager')
        ->select('id', 'name')
        ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
        ->get();
```

then just pass to your view $employeeAm and $employeePm then in your view

```
@foreach ($employeePm as $employee)
     <option value="{{ $employee->id }}">{{ $employee->name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

same as for your `$employeeAm`

Comment: Didn't try that and I'm sure that would work. How would you pass both variables to the view? return view('projects/create', ['employeeAm' => $employeeAm, 'employeePm' => $employeePm]); ? And can you explain to me why my method didn't work when it worked in a previous post (linked in the comments above)

Comment: to pass both variables to the view you can use like this:<br>
`return view('projects/create')->with('employeeAm', $employeeAm)->with('employeePm', $employeePm);`

Comment: the 'employeeAm' and employeePm is the name you will use in your view to access the $employeeAm and $employeePm variable.
for me i think why your method didn't work because first of all you only passed the $employees variable from your controller to your view so he didn't recognize the $am and $pm variable in the view.